# Why does cat-ing this small file cause the Mac terminal emulator to minimize?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

In hex, the file is

```
1b 5b 32 74
```

ie. [ESC] then [2t.

Printing this file's contents to the terminal on mac sends the window to the tray. I can't get the same behaviour anywhere else or find any documentation on this particular escape sequence.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the [Xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) control sequence for iconify window.

An excerpt:

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
          Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions).
          These controls may be disabled using the allowWindowOps
          resource.  Valid values for the first (and any additional
          parameters) are:
            Ps = 1  -> De-iconify window.
            Ps = 2  -> Iconify window.
            Ps = 3  ;  x ;  y -> Move window to [x, y].
          [...]
```

CSI is the control sequence initiator (`ESC [`). `t` is the "command", which allows for several types of window manipulation, the exact manipulation determined by parameters (indicated by `Ps`) that precede the `t`. The parameter 2 indicates the window should be iconified, which on Mac OS means to send it to the doc.